# Graphics Issues When In Games RTX 2080 Super

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

So, this issue happens mainly when I'm playing games. I'm not sure if it happens out of games. Its not possible to tell.

The issue is that some white lines appear when I'm opening a game up. Like its launcher and when in game. The game does not look like it's supposed to. Some graphics are messed up and also have a massive hit on my frames.

The issue is most noticeable when I open Minecraft. This is in the launcher and in game.

Here are some pictures of the lines. These are not supposed to be there for those who havent played Minecraft.

[image: https://gyazo.com/9fce14bb34712e8799a2ca0621de655e]
[image: https://gyazo.com/57abbaa51ed2496ac946116c8694a0e6]
[image: https://gyazo.com/3138328b6eca04f78a67ce49b90778b9]
[image: https://gyazo.com/bd8ea5e6b2a932c5fdefaeca17d50609]
[image: https://gyazo.com/78c2a16a4279e733b8c858e09d996222]

I'm on a Windows 10 home
Computer Specs:

[image: https://gyazo.com/8e4c343f76a4829a7a447f457be8f373]

Comment: Most likely a faulty graphics card. Have you tried re-seating the card? Updated the drivers?

Comment: Looking at the screenshots I'd suspect driver or addon software. The desktop in shots 2 and 5 look fine while the game is messed up. I believe that Minecraft Java uses OpenGL while Windows itself would use DirectX for desktop compositing so it points at a problem with OpenGL. Do *all* games do this or just some? As Niall says updating the drivers would be a good first step.

Comment: @NiallJones I wouldn't say that hardware failure is most likely. I have had artifacts and issues like these in the past, and it was always due to driver and software issues, never due to a hardware fault. It is an option, but I wouldn't say the most likely one. Minecraft especially is tricky in this regard.

Comment: I have tried re installing me drivers. But I have not tried re seating the driver.

Comment: It also happens in games such as rust and League of legends. So at this point its probably every game

Comment: I also make sure to keep my drivers updated ALL THE TIME

Comment: Also, when i took out the GPU and used my backup one. All the errors just STOPPED.

Comment: I have even sent my card back to the provider and they said after doing various tests. NOTHING has happened and everything is work as expected